# Magento 2.0.7 - modify search terms

Tags: magento2

I want to modify the search facility so that queries are more strict (narrowed).

For example:

`Audi A8 2008` searches for: `Audi` AND `A8` AND `2008` (not: `Audi` OR `A8` OR `2008`)

How can I achieve that?